# Unable to mount "lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso" on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mount, lubuntu, 15.04, iso, macosx

I am trying to create an installer DVD from the above .iso image and am unable to do so. 
When attempting to use Disc Utility to mount the image I am alerted, "Unable to burn 'lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso' (Resource temporarily unavailable).
Double-clicking the image (to mount it to the desktop) results in the Warning "The following disk images couldn't be opened" Image: "lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso" Reason: Resource temporarily unavilable.
Finally, Toast does not permit mounting the image.
I have tried several different methods of mounting this disc image, all to no avail.

Are there any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the downloaded file is corrupted. On a Mac OS, you can compute the MD5 sum of the file from a terminal using

```
md5sum /path/to/lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

I think you can even view it in the file's properties alternatively.
Then compare that checksum to the one given on the download page. If they do match, ignore this answer, the problem is elsewhere...

Else, redownload the ISO file.

Hint: If you download it using BitTorrent, you can be sure the download is correct, as corrupted chunks are discarded automatically and redownloaded until they match their checksum.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. The MD5 result does indeed match one of those given on the download page, specifically : b66f9a0a87289be57cb3eb84f153c01d

This leads me to believe the issue lies elsewhere.